# Fastest way to determine what value of a list appears first in a string

Tags: string, vba, excel, position

I have a list of strings in a column on a sheet (let us say "A"), like this:

```
     A
BJS-LAX-GRU
CAN-ORD-MIA-BOG
NRT-LAX-JFK-LIM
```

And then I have a different list on a different sheet (let us say "B"), like this:

```
 A
LAX
MEX
MIA
JFK
```

So I want to know which value of the second list appears first in each string of the first list, and then I need to write that value next to the string. In the example, I would get:

```
     A              B
BJS-LAX-GRU        LAX
CAN-ORD-MIA-BOG    MIA
NRT-LAX-JFK-LIM    LAX
```

I wrote the following code, which works perfectly:

```
Dim aux As Integer
Dim cur As String

For j = 1 To Sheets("A").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    aux = 100
    cur = ""
    For k = 1 To Sheets("B").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(Sheets("A").Cells(j, 1).Value, Sheets("B").Cells(k, 1).Value) < aux And InStr(Sheets("A").Cells(j, 1).Value, Sheets("B").Cells(k, 1).Value) <> 0 Then
            cur = Sheets("B").Cells(k, 1).Value
            aux = InStr(Sheets("A").Cells(j, 1).Value, cur)
        End If
    Next k
    Sheets("A").Cells(j, 2) = cur
Next j
```

The problem is that I am aware that this code is extremely inefficient, since those lists have 200K+ rows. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: `wrote the following code, which works perfectly:` ask in code review. Amazing community there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By putting the values in Arrays and using the Application.Match to find match this should be pretty quick:

```
Sub findmatch()

Dim inarr() As Variant
Dim oarr() As Variant
Dim i As Long
Dim str() As String
Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set tws = Sheets("Sheet2") 'This sheet is where the lookup list is located
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") ' this is the list of names
Set rng = tws.Range("A1", tws.Cells(tws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
inarr = ws.Range("A1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value
ReDim oarr(1 To UBound(inarr, 1), 1 To 1)

For i = 1 To UBound(inarr, 1)
    str = Split(inarr(i, 1), "-")
    For j = 0 To UBound(str)
        Dim fnd
        fnd = Application.Match(str(j), rng, 0)
        If Not IsError(fnd) Then
            oarr(i, 1) = rng(fnd)
            Exit For
        End If
        oarr(i, 1) = "None"
    Next j
Next i

ws.Range("B1").Resize(UBound(oarr, 1)).Value = oarr

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

If the individual values are all 3 letters then something like:

```
=MID(C3,SMALL(IFERROR(SEARCH($F$3:$F$6,C3),200),1),3)
```

Entered as an array formula using `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

[image]

Comment: You made the formula copy/paste friendly this time =PPP

Comment: It's the least I could do (and I always do the least i can do)

Comment: I was just teasing you! <33

Answer (score 1):

You can optimise your code by not reading values multiple times , eg

*Sheets("B").Cells(k, 1).Value*

is read more than once, read it into a variable once per scan, you do it with other values too.

As an alternative strategy have a look at the excel Search and Find functions